# How to pull changes from a pull request thats already checkout?

Tags: git, pull-request

I have checked out a PR using:

```
git fetch origin pull/pull_req_ID/head:NEWBRANCHNAME
```

However, I can't pull changes to my local branch from that PR.

Comment: Pull requests are not technically a git concept, only an added abstraction commonly used in online git workflows, often with the help of platforms like Github or Bitbucket. And PRs are not branches, so I guess you're somehow trying to pull the destination branch into which the PR was made... ?

Comment: yah, i have created a local branch of that PR. and is it possible to pull from that PR.

Comment: You answered "yeah" (if I got it well) but the following is in contradiction. You can't create a branch out of a PR, only from another branch (or a commit). Where are you checking on PRs? Look at the description, there should have two branches involved, one source branch (whatever it is called) and a destination branch. Pull the destination branch into your local branch.

Comment: I think i can create a local branch out of a PR. thats what the command in my question does. Anyway once i did that, i can just attach the tracking info of the remote branch of the PR. then it would work i think

Comment: The command in your question creates no local branch, only a remote-tracking branch. And this is not "out of a PR", since `NEWBRANCHNAME` is a branch. The "pull request id" is an abstraction meant to help you find it easier, maybe, but at the end of the day, you're just fetching a branch.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand the question correctly, another developer has pushed changes to a PR after you initially fetched it, and you want to get the latest updates. This should work:

```
git checkout NEWBRANCHNAME
git fetch origin pull/pull_req_ID/head
git rebase FETCH_HEAD  # Or git merge FETCH_HEAD
```

Bitbucket example:

```
git fetch origin pull-requests/101/from:pr/101
git checkout pr/101

# ...New changes pushed to PR #101 by another developer

git fetch origin pull-requests/101/from
git rebase FETCH_HEAD
```

Gitlab example:

```
git fetch origin merge-requests/101/head:mr/101
git checkout mr/101

# ...New changes pushed to MR #101 by another developer

git fetch origin merge-requests/101/head
git rebase FETCH_HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

Pull requests are features of online repos (like Github) that basically mean "this person wants to merge *these changes* from *this* branch to *that* branch". It is *NOT* an actual branch, rather it presents the changes from *someone's* branch, allows discussion/review of those changes, before getting it merged to some *base* branch.

In Git terms, it's basically a request to do a `git merge`.

So what you need to do is to check the pull request info, find the SOURCE (branch to be merged) and the DEST (branch to merge into). Here's an example with Github:

[image: pr]

where the SOURCE branch is `fix-bug-1234` and the DEST branch is `master`.

Then do:

```
git fetch origin <SOURCE> 
git fetch origin <DEST>
git checkout <DEST>         # You will now be in DEST branch
git pull                    # Update copy of base branch
git merge origin/<SOURCE>   # Merge changes from SOURCE to DEST
git push origin <DEST>      # Push the update DEST branch
```

For me, it's better to create a local copy of the SOURCE branch.

```
git fetch origin            # Fetch all branches, both SOURCE and DEST
git checkout <SOURCE>       # Create a local copy of the SOURCE branch
git pull                    # You now have the changes to merge
git checkout <DEST>         # You will now be in DEST branch
git pull                    # Update copy of base branch
git merge <SOURCE>          # Merge changes from SOURCE to DEST
git push origin <DEST>      # Push the update DEST branch
```

If you don't want to deal with this command-line stuff, online repo's usually have a way to merge or accept pull requests via their UI.

- If you are on Github, see their docs on [merging a pull request](https://help.github.com/en/articles/merging-a-pull-request)
- If you are on Bitbucket, see their [tutorial on pull requests](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request)

Answer (score 0):

if you are in your local branch:

```
git pull
git merge NEWBRANCHNAME
```

Comment: There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.

Comment: `git merge NEWBRANCHNAME`

Answer (score 0):

Start with:

`git pull`

You must switch to branch that will receiver the changes.

`git checkout old_branch`

After, make the merge with branch that you did pull request.

`git merge changed_branch`